# Protect Sheet with specific condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to prevent a user from deleting/adding rows and columns on my Google Sheet, however, when I protect the sheet, I can't specifically ask it to just prevent those, it blocks data entry, hiding/unhiding rows/columns etc. What I thought about is to put a checkbox on a cell, so the user can still hide/unhide certain rows if needed, however, my script doesn't work when the sheet is protected.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var sheetName = 'Fund Request';

var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName),
    status = sh.getRange('A20').getValues();

function showHideRow(v, i) {
    // [[row, numberRows]]
    var rows = [[21,180]];

    return v[0]
           ? sh.showRows.apply(sh, rows[i])
           : sh.hideRows.apply(sh, rows[i])
};

status.forEach(showHideRow);
}
```

Any ideas? Would be nice if a user can still use the sheet normally except for adding/deleting rows and columns even though it's protected.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply the question in my previous answer. I can't see how you can have user role to allow hide/unhide rows, but block add/remove rows

Comment: I cannot understand about `Would be nice if a user can still use the sheet normally except for adding/deleting rows and columns even though it's protected.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @tanaike,My goal is for the users to be able to fill out the sheet, hide/unhide rows as they need it, but not be able to add/delete rows or columns. The form that I created already have enough rows to accommodate what they need to input data, however, it varies. Sometimes they only need 1 row, sometimes they need 100s! Since I already know the max number of rows, I set it already on the sheet. All they need to do is hide/unhide it. They don't need to add/delete any. Hence, my question. I need the sheet protected, but allow them to hide/unhide, but not allow them to add/delete.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to protect a sheet from users and you want to show and hide rows in the protected sheet by the users. From your replying, I understood like this. If my understanding is correct, in the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be achieved because of the specification of Google side. I apologize for this. If I misunderstood your goal, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, your understanding is correct. So for now, there's really no way to protect a sheet and at the same time, allow users to hide/unhide rows? If that's the case, is there no work-around for this? Maybe, another solution you can think of? Thank you for responding as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I confirmed that my understanding of `You want to protect a sheet from users and you want to show and hide rows in the protected sheet by the users.` is correct. But I have to deeply apologize for my poor skill. About `So for now, there's really no way to protect a sheet and at the same time, allow users to hide/unhide rows? If that's the case, is there no work-around for this? Maybe, another solution you can think of?`, in the current stage, I have no clear answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, what you want cannot be achieved as protecting a sheet results in no changes in the content being possible. This goes for adding/removing rows/columns as well and unfortunately Google does not allow in the current stage to select which types of actions to limit in your spreadsheet.

You may benefit from using an `onChange` trigger and if the above actions are detected, display an alert.

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'REMOVE_ROW')
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please do not remove any rows!');
}
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script Ui Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui).

Comment: Hi! With this code you've shared, will this prevent the actions taken? Or will it just show the alert but do the actions anyway? Also, when I tried your code, nothing happened. I applied the code, tried to delete a row on my sheet, but nothing happened.

Comment: The `onChange` is an installable trigger so you will have to install it *first*. It will just show the alert however. Like mentioned, you cannot protect a sheet while also allowing the users to hide/unhide the rows/cols. @Kelvs